# Drupal 7 taxonomy add term missing url path settings

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I'm working with a Drupal 7 installation, I watched a video that shows how to work with taxonomy, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qmr2HW6CtJQ but when I go to "add term" to create a new term in my newly created vocabulary, the "URL Path Settings" was missing which has to generate automatic url alias that was shown at 04:15 of the video.

How to get this to show up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to enable path module (core) and [pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto)